# Objective C forward declaration and type compatibility

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, forward-declaration

I have code like following:

```
#import "ViewModelBase.h"

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewModelBase* viewModel;
@end
```

Then I need to do something like following:

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@class ViewModelSubclass;

@interface ViewControllerB : ViewControllerA
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewModelSubclass* viewModel;
@end
```

Where ViewModelSubclass.h is not supposed to be imported to ViewControllerB.h, only to .m file.
However, ViewModelSubclass is supposed to be subclass of ViewModelBase.
This is done to hide interface of ViewModelSubclass from clients of ViewControllerB.
How do I solve "Property type 'ViewModelSubclass*' is incompatible with type 'ViewModelBAse*' inherited from ViewControllerA" warning?
Or what is a better way to do it?

Comment: maybe im wrong, but i dont think you can override a property in a super class like that

Comment: @Fonix, it works, I'm not actually override a property, I 'overscpecify' it's type

Comment: but the property in the super class and the sub class have the same name... but different types, so the compiler is probably confused

Comment: @Fonix, yes, but final types are compatible, so I'm looking for a way to tell it to compiler and 'convince' it that everything OK.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

don't use like this

```
#import<ViewControllerA.h>
```

try to use like

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
```

I think it will solve your problem

Comment: My fault, I really meant quotation marks, not angle bracket

Comment: please explain briefly what you exactly want to do? and post Xcode code don't write its own. so we will help you in that

Comment: Now example code is correct, I'm looking for a way to convince the compiler that forward declared ViewModelSubclass is actually a subclass of ViewModelBase.